# Unable to copy file from /opt/lampp/htdocs to /home/username/ using PHP

Tags: permissions, php

I'm running Lampp in Ubuntu, Working in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` folder.

The htdocs folder has write permissions enabled  (I don't remember the exact command I ran to do that). I'm able to copy files from That folder to my home folder using cp/mv without any errors.

But I'm unable to do that using PHP. `File.txt` is placed in the htdocs folder and I want to move it to `/home/username`. I have tried using "copy" but it says "Failed to open stream" error and the Shell_exec / exec command won't show any error but doesn't copy the file either.

Comment: can you show the apache2/error.log? if there is a problem with your PHP-file it should be seen there

Comment: It shows the Permission Denied error, But same command ran from terminal works fine without sudo.

Comment: Or simply can you guide me to move my lamp folder somehow to home, So the user directly gets permission.

Comment: that is not a good idea, cause the security would be really bad. i would make the folders r/w with `chmod 755 *dir*`

Comment: Alright. I did that but still I'm unable to copy/move the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder your PHP script is trying to write to will probably be owned by the root user. Your PHP script is running under the www-data user if you're using a default Ubuntu/Apache/PHP setup.

As such you need to:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data *dir*
chmod -R g+w *dir*
```

you don't have to do the second line if `ls -al` shows you this

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

If your PHP is running under a different user then just change the user in the first line of code.

that should fix your problem.

Comment: It worked, Daemon was the user running the php.